# How to deploy web application to existing Jetty using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, web-deployment

Using `mvn tomcat7:deploy` I can deploy a web application to Tomcat. But how can I do this with jetty? As far as I understand it, the Maven Jetty Plugin launches its own Jetty server but can I configure it to use my existing Jetty server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jetty Maven plugin with either the **run-war** or **deploy-war** tasks.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#running-assembled-webapp-as-war

Comment: Are you sure? There are no parameters for the jetty connection. To me it looks like it uses its own Jetty.

Comment: You are right... for remote deployment maybe the Cargo Maven plugin can help you.